# Combining 2 sqlalchemy queries and sorting

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm using the results of one query to process another and then add that data to the original query object. I'd then like to order the results by that data.

Here's what I have at the moment:

```
def driver():
    sess = session()
    data = sess.query(DriversConstructors).filter(DriversConstructors.TYPE_ID==1).all()
    for driver in data:
        p = sess.query(func.sum(FantasyResults.POINTS)).filter(FantasyResults.DRIVER_CONSTRUCTOR_ID==driver._ID).scalar()
        driver.points = int(p)
    sess.close()
    return data
```

so basically the results need to be ordered by points.

I'm pretty confident there is a much better way of doing this so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood correctly, what you need is a JOIN and some grouping in order to move the operation to the database system:

```
def driver(type_id=1):
    sess = session()
    try:
        return sess.query(DriversConstructors).\
            outerjoin(FantasyResults,
                      FantasyResults.DRIVER_CONSTRUCTOR_ID == DriversConstructors._ID). \
            filter(DriversConstructors.TYPE_ID == type_id). \
            group_by(DriversConstructors._ID). \
            order_by(func.sum(FantasyResults.POINTS)). \
            all()

    finally:
        sess.close()
```

Comment: So this is ordering by the points but I don't actually seem to be able to access the points data, so for instance doing the following:

    drivers = driver()
    for driver in drivers:
        print(driver.POINTS)

gives an error

Comment: That's as simple as `query(DriversConstructors, func.sum(FantasyResults.POINTS))`, but note that then the return value is a tuple of driver constructor and the sum. If you for some reason must have points as an attribute of a driver constructor, look into using query-time expressions as mapped attributes: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/mapped_sql_expr.html#query-time-sql-expressions-as-mapped-attributes – or monkeypatch points to the driver instances from the tuple, as you have done before.